# Surprising order in python set combination methods

Tags: python, hashmap

I am aware that `set()` in python doesn't have an order as it is implemented as a hash table. However, I was a little surprised to solve a question which involved order using `set.intersection()`.

So I am given two lists with an order, say for example, denoting some ranking or sequence of occurrence. I have to find the element that is common to both lists and has highest order (occurs the first) in the two lists. For example,

```
List1 = ['j','s','l','p','t']
List2 = ['b','d','q','s','y','j']
```

should output `'s'` as it is the second best in `List1` and occurs the first in `List2`.

If you convert each of the lists into sets and take an intersection `Set1.intersection(Set2)`, you get a set `set(['s', 'j'])`. In my case I could convert this into a list and spit out the first element and this was approximately O(n1 + n2).

I was happy to solve this interview question (all test passed), but I am amazed how could I pull off such a order based problem using python `set`.

Does anyone have a clue how this is working? What's a possible case, that this could breakdown?

**EDIT: This seems to be like a stoke of luck case, so if you have a good solution for this problem, it will be also appreciated**

Comment: just don't rely on the order of `set`. It can change depending on the versions of python.

Comment: I agree that it seems spurious. I just wanted to know how it is working in this case. And what test case could break down my code, which surprisingly didn't happen in the automated test cases.

Comment: The answer to "how it is working" is "luck".  The fact that sets are unordered doesn't mean they will never give you the order you want.  It means you never know what order they will give you.

Comment: Could you clarify your desired output on the following example: `list1 = ['a','b','c]; list2=['c','b','a']`? with explanation please. (I posted this in a comment to an answer but it doesn't fit there)

Answer (score 1):

I found a `O(n1+n2)` approach. Commented code follows. The trick is to create a lookup table (not a dictionary, a simple array) to index the minimum position of the letters in both lists, and then find the minimum of the sum of those positions and the associated letter.

```
List1 = ['j','s','l','p','t']
List2 = ['b','d','q','s','y','j']

# unreachable max value to initialize the slots
maxlen = max(len(List1),len(List2))+1000

# create empty slot_array (initialized to values higher than last letter pos
# for both lists (the value is greater than any "valid" position)
# first pos (index 0) is for letter "a", last pos is for letter "z"

slot_array = [[maxlen,maxlen] for x in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]

# scan both lists, and update the position if lower than the one in slot_array
for list_index,the_list in enumerate((List1,List2)):
    print(list_index)
    for letter_index,letter in enumerate(the_list):
        slot = slot_array[ord(letter)-ord('a')]
        if slot[list_index]>letter_index:
            slot[list_index] = letter_index

# now compute minimum of sum of both minimum positions for each letter
min_value = maxlen*2

for i,(a,b) in enumerate(slot_array):
    sab = a+b
    if sab < min_value:
        min_value = sab
        min_index = i

# result is the letter with the minimal sum
print(chr(min_index+ord('a')))
```

Comment: That's a nice strategy! In the hindsight, my initial attempt to use set was to have a lookup table. Since I knew I'd have to, well, "look it up". I was given 15 min to solve it. By the time I found the intersection. I jumped quickly to submit the answer.

To be honest, however, the problem had strings instead of characters. I abstracted due to NDA. Is a lookup table for strings that straightforward?

Comment: oh, looks that your [mcve] was really too minimal :) In 15 minutes I could have come up with a crappy O(n**2) double loop. For strings, it would require to use a dictionary, but I think it could be done in a rather similar way. I can have a go at it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension could do the job:

```
Set2 = set(List2)
[x for x in List1 if x in Set2]
```

This will maintain the order of `List1`, you could do the same for `List2` too.

You can then call `next` on the list comprehension (or a generator to be more efficient) to get the first match.

Comment: As I mentioned, I know a way to solve the problem
Set1 = set(List1)
Set2 = set(List2)
ans = list(Set1.intersection(Set2))[0]
and it works.  I wonder how??

Comment: @AseemDua> no, you don't need to convert both lists, just the one you use for inclusion testing (and even that is not strictly necessary, it's just much more efficient)

Comment: the idea is _not_ to convert to `set` oryou can lose the order.

Comment: but if list1 have duplicated element,the answer can be wrong. And also, its o(n * m)

Comment: @herokingsley: right! so listcomp isn't an option here

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, what do you then suggest is a good approach?

Comment: @AseemDua in that case, I'm not sure we can do better than O(N**2). I'll think about it.